# Linear Least Squares with Linear Equality Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, least-squares

I want to solve the least squares problem $(Ax-b)^2$ with no intercept term for linear regression with the constraint that the sum of the weights is equal to 1.

I am trying to get the closed form solution of it but couldn't. Any suggestion?

Comment: The question is pretty unclear (to me, at least). You're probably not going to get much help unless you do a better job of describing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Could you address my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is given by:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\arg \min_{x} & \quad & \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x = 1
\end{alignat*}
$$

The Lagrangian is given by:

$$ L \left( x, \nu \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \nu \left( \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x - 1 \right) $$

From KKT Conditions the optimal values of $ \hat{x}, \hat{\nu} $ obeys:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
{A}^{T} A & \boldsymbol{1} \\ 
\boldsymbol{1}^{T} & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} \\ 
\hat{\nu}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
{A}^{T} b \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now all needed is to solve the above with any Linear System Solver.